# test folder in source folder in a java project - vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Why am I getting this paint plucker icon, every time I rename a Java package as test in Visual Code Studio:

[image: Renaming]

I just want to know about how these Java packages work inside at the low level.

Comment: It doesn't look like a paint plucker to me, but a test-tube.

Comment: This is an icon theme. Do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: The icon does not matter. Check some tutorials or Java text books, for example [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html). The convention with Maven and Gradle is to have a `src/` folder, and below that `main` and `test` for the main and test code, respectively. But you could put your code wherever you feel like, you'd just point the test runners and compilers at it.